# How to export a const value in Next.js with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, next.js, react-props

I am trying to export a `const` value called `views` from BlogPost.js to blog.js.

Here is `BlogPost.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import useSWR from 'swr';
import format from 'comma-number';

import {
  useColorMode,
  Heading,
  Text,
  Flex,
  Box,
  Badge,
  Link,
  Tooltip
} from '@chakra-ui/react';

import fetcher from '../lib/fetcher';

const BlogPost = (frontMatter) => {
  const {
    title,
    modality,
    summary,
    image,
    brand,
    lastPublishedOn,
    firstCreatedOn
  } = frontMatter;
  const { colorMode } = useColorMode();
  const secondaryTextColor = {
    light: 'gray.700',
    dark: 'gray.400'
  };

  const slug = frontMatter.__resourcePath
    .replace('Blog\\', '')
    .replace('.mdx', '');

  const { data } = useSWR(`/api/page-views?id=${slug}`, fetcher);
  const views = data?.total;
  //console.log('views ', views); //This is the one I am trying to export. 

  return (
    <>
      <Flex
        width="100%"
        align="flex-start"
        justifyContent="space-between"
        flexDirection={['column', 'row']}
      >
        <Box alignItems="flex-start" mt={4} ml={0} mb={2}>
          ...
        </Box>
      </Flex>
      <Flex width="100%" align="flex-start" justifyContent="flex-start">
        <Box alignItems="flex-start" mb={12}>
       ...
        </Box>
      </Flex>
    </>
  );
};

//export {views}; //IF I did this here, I get `Export 'views' is not defined ERROR.`
export default BlogPost;
```

Then, in `blog.js`, I do;

```js
import BlogPost, {views} from '../components/BlogPost';
```

However, this throws a **'Export 'views' is not defined` error**.

Can you please assist with rewriting this? The goal is to get the `views` const value available in `blog.js`, not using this syntax or anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I need to note that, answering this question with a code example doesn't help you for improving development skills. Because the component structure doesn't look right. That's why you are having an issue with passing a data to outside.

This usage doesn't look clean to me. This `views` value is a dynamic one. So, sharing it with `exporting` doesn't make sense. And, is this `BlogPost` component designed for showing posts or fetching them, or both? I think you need to split the usage for a cleaner solution like `BlogsRoute` and as a child: `BlogPosts`. And I would call the endpoint in `BlogsRoute`, pass the data to `BlogPosts` and only render it, and finally, I could share `views` wherever I wanted.

I assume that you were trying to export the `views` data to the parent component of `BlogPost`. (If not, I mean, if you were trying to pass this `views` data to an irrelevant route or component, you should choose a data store like ReactContext or Redux, that's another question to answer)
**Example 1:**

```
const BlogPostsRoute = () => {
  const { data } = useSWR(`/api/page-views?id=${slug}`, fetcher);
  // use data.total as whatever you want here
  ...

  // now, BlogPost only get views data from outside and doesn't need to control/export data
  return <BlogPost views={data ? data.total : []}/>
}
```

Another solution could be passing a callback function to `BlogPost` component like `onViewsFetched` and call it after onSuccess. I believe that SWR should have an `onSuccess` function as an option.

**Example 2:**

```
const BlogPost = (frontMatter) => {
  const { onViewsFetched /*, other props... */ } = frontMatter;

...

  const { data } = useSWR(`/api/page-views?id=${slug}`, fetcher, { onSuccess: onViewsFetched });
```

and lastly, you can use the `BlogPost` again in your parent component:

```
const BlogPostsRoute = () => {
    return <BlogPost onViewsFetched={(data, key, config) => {
        // this is the place you can use data?.total
        ...
    } />
}
```

Comment: Can you offer a code solution? If not, it's not helpful on StackOverflow. Thanks.

Comment: As you can see, I don't know how to answer questions correctly here. I've just tried to explain what was the reason for having this problem first. If you should build your component structure better in the first place, there won't be any question like this.

Comment: Thanks @ozgurkececioglu - I did Example 2... How to retrieve 'onViewsFetched' under `blog.js`... Also, the last bit about `const BlogPostsRoute = () => {` is not clear to me. Where should I put it? Inside the default export of the parent JS file? It throws a `}' expected.` error.

Comment: I was referring to the parent component of `<BlogPost />`. I think it is in `blog.js`. You should find a way to use this `data?.total` inside rendering. I think you are trying to achieve something different.

Comment: So, what is `BlogPostsRoute`?

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction You know we mostly consider our pages like routes because they have a path in the URL. So, while creating a new page, you will give a name to your component which rendering your page like "BlogPosts, BlogPostsPage, BlogPostsRoute", and most probably, your path for this route will be `/blogs-posts/${postId}`. I used the name `BlogPostsRoute` to refer to an imaginary parent component for `BlogPost`. That's all.